# How can OpenCV2 (specifically version 2.4.9.1) be installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, opencv

I have a large program that is dependent on OpenCV2. The ultimate aim is to modify that program such that it is dependent on OpenCV3 or OpenCV4, but I do not have the time to learn how to rewrite the program at this time, so...

How might OpenCV2 (specifically version 2.4.9.1) be installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

The dependencies of the program as they are now are as follows:

```
sudo apt install  \
    python-dev    \
    libasound-dev \
    python-pyaudio\
    libopencv-dev \
    python-opencv \
    python-tk
```

The key packages for OpenCV 2.4.9.1 needed are as follows:

- `python-opencv=2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1`
- `libopencv-dev=2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1`

How might this be done? Are there options I have not considered?

Comment: It seems to very difficult as you need to download packages [from 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/opencv). Also note that latest version with security updates is *2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1*. So consider to use 16.04 LTS distribution or *schroot* or Docker container with it.